# Print the list of winter bash 2014 hats as a list of checkboxes in GFM format

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, markdown

In Winter Bash 2014, 
since [there is no easy way to see *the hats I'm missing* per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245768/distinguishing-hats-earned-on-current-site),
I decided to use [Gists](https://gist.github.com/) for that.
A perhaps not so well-known feature of GitHub Flavered Markdown (GFM) format used everywhere on GitHub is that if you write bullet point lists with embedded `[ ]` like this:

```
- [ ] Bill Lumbergh: answer 5 questions on Saturday (UTC)
- [ ] On The Road: ask using the app
- [ ] Bugdroid: use the Android app
- [ ] Not a cherry: use the iOS app
- [ ] I Voted Today: vote limit and 10+ questions
```

These will be rendered not as regular bullet point lists but a list of checkboxes:
clicking on an item will toggle the checkbox, triggering a commit.

Just one little problem: 
there's no obviously easy way to copy-paste the hat names and descriptions from the [Winter Bash website](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/).
So I cooked up this simple soup (pun totally intended) using Python's [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from urllib import request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


URL = 'http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/'


def load_html_doc(url):
    cached_file = 'page.html'
    if os.path.isfile(cached_file) and os.path.getsize(cached_file):
        with open(cached_file) as fh:
            html_doc = fh.read()
    else:
        html_doc = request.urlopen(url).read()
        with open(cached_file, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(html_doc)
    return html_doc


def get_soup(url):
    html_doc = load_html_doc(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(html_doc)


def print_hats_as_gfm_checkboxes(soup):
    for box in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'box'}):
        name = box.find(attrs={'class': 'hat-name'}).text
        description = box.find(attrs={'class': 'hat-description'}).text
        print('- [ ] {}: {}'.format(name, description))


def print_pretty(soup):
    print(soup.prettify())


def main():
    soup = get_soup(URL)
    print_hats_as_gfm_checkboxes(soup)
    # print_pretty(soup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This produces a list of all the hats in the right format to be suitable for copy-pasting into a Gist.

Anything to improve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Some people make the poor excuse that [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)

> recommends that `python` continue to refer to `python2` for the time being

but this doesn't even apply to you since yours only supports Python 3!

Use this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Your code could do with doc comments; at least `load_html_doc` could. These don't need to be long.

There's nothing wrong with caching files locally, but I would suggest writing to `tempfile.gettempdir()`.

`request.urlopen` returns a file-like object. Moments later you use `with` on a file object but you neglect to do so on `request.urlopen`'s!

I would do an early return in `load_html_doc`.

Your `os.path.isfile(cached_file)` check is strange; if it's a directory instead you don't actually deal with the resulting problem. It's not a big deal, but I would use `os.path.exists` to prevent it looking like you're actually checking.

`cached_file` would be better as a default argument, and I'd call it `cache_file` or even `cache_path`. IMHO `fh` isn't that great a name either.

Here's the updated code, still writing to the same file:

```
def load_html_doc(url, cache_file='page.html'):
    if os.path.exists(cache_file) and os.path.getsize(cache_file):
        with open(cache_file) as cache:
            return cache.read()

    with request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
        html_doc = webpage.read()
    with open(cache_file, 'wb') as cache:
        cache.write(html_doc)
    return html_doc
```

After all of the comments on `load_html_doc`, I'm sad (happy?) to say there isn't much to talk about with the rest of it. I would remove the `# print_pretty(soup)` comment, though.